# TypeEnum not working

Tags: java, hibernate

The type `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.TMSchema` is not visible when I import it

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> parameter : parameters) {

                    try{
                        String s2 = (String) parameter.getValue();

                        try{
                            String value = (String) parameter.getValue();
                            query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(),TypeEnum.value);
                        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                            query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(),parameter.getValue());
                        }

                    }catch(ClassCastException e){
                        query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(),parameter.getValue());    
                    }
}
```

Comment: @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) used...still not working

Comment: TMSchema class doesn't have the public modifier, so it is only visible in it's package. What do you want to achieve in your inner try block?

Comment: if it can't set the value for enum then it set it as string...inside map there is some key which are type of enum

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand you, but if you want to use the values in your "parameters" map as query parameters, you can do it as you've done in your catch, according to this link:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29
Please let me know if I misunderstand you, but I think this will always work for you:

query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(),parameter.getValue());

Comment: Thanx...but i need to pass values in setParameter() like string,long,enum etc...so how it works??

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on what we talked about in our comments. I'm not a hibernate mage and I'm pretty sure there is a better solution. Since you want to set the parameter types, you can use instaceof to determine,what kind of parameter you are using. According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29) link you can use somethin like this in you for loop:

```
if(parameter.getValue() instaceof String){
   query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue(), new StringType());
} else if (parameter.getValue() instanceof Integer){
   query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue(), new IntegerTypeType())
} else if(...)
```

And so on. To use this solution you have to create an `org.hibernate.Query` query and also import the necessary types in the `org.hibernate.type` package.

Of course, you can use a switch statement instead of if conditions. But if I could, I would still prefer the more simple setParameter method, where you only have to add the name of the parameter and the value:

```
query.setParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue());
```

Hope that helps.